# Download csv file with dynamic filter values

Tags: csv, tableau-api

I have a dashboard with various filters and a data table that I would like to download as a .csv file. I have tried the trick of just appending ".csv" to the end of the url and that works fine for downloading *all* of the data, however I need to  have my csv file contain only the *filtered* data that is shown in my data table.

I can manually apply a filter in the url with something like `Value="FilteredItem"` and this behaves as I expect with a csv file, however for this I have to specify what I am filtering on and I need this to be dynamic based on what the user of my dashboard has selected/entered for the filters.

What is the correct way to append to the url to pass through the filters such that the resulting csv file contains only the filtered data?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [Export All](https://extensiongallery.tableau.com/products/25) dashboard Extension for Tableau 2018.2 or later.

If you have an earlier version, this [method](http://www.vizwiz.com/2014/03/the-greatest-tableau-tip-ever-exporting.html) is another way to accomplish the same thing.  You can construct the URLs with all of the filter values that you need.